# Shell folders notifications and icons

Tags: shell, delphi, winapi, directory

I'm looking for someone with experience in the Windows Shell to give me a few hints.

I'm making a simple shell/filesystem browser using Delphi 2010, and it's partially functional, but I have a couple of issues (for now). The code is a bit too large to post and I'm not sure which parts are relevant.

1. `SHChangeNotifyRegister()` works OK with folders which are either pure filesystem (like `"e:\x\y"`) or virtual (start with `"::{clsid}"`). Regardless of parameters passed (event flags, locking; recursion/subfolders is always false), it refuses to return `RMDIR` and `RENAMEDIR` notifications for folders like `"c:\users\myname\music"` (which have virtual paths, like `"::{this pc clsid}\music")`.  Can this be fixed? PIDLs are obtained with `SHCreateItemFromParsingName()`.
2. `IShellItemImageFactory` returns no images for HomeGroup subfolders (one of several image getting procedures returns blank paper icons. Others return errors). I've prepared custom images for this purpose.  I'm just wondering about this.

Comment: I'd delve into source. I know of [sharpe](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpe/) (delphi) but there are [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_alternative_shells_for_Windows).

Comment: For number 2 I image you have to use a debugger. HomeGroup is dead/dying on Windows 10.

Comment: They probably come as a different type of event. Try registering for all event types and print out the events that come in.

Comment: Sir Tac, i tried installing sharpe to see what it is, but i ended up with black screen and only ctrl-alt-tab working. fortunately i was able to google the problem and regedit to reclaim my windows. browsing the source now. Anders, i don't know what debugger you mean. Jonathan, i tried all events flag and got a dozen of extended events for each mkdir/rmdir, described on MS site as "schne_extended_event: not currently used".

Comment: Trying the pidls from the shell tree creation (ishellfolder enumeration), i notice their change notifications start occurring only after the first grandchild node pidl is "bound" (ishellfolder.bindtoobject is called) to a child node (so i have to bind "e:" and "e:\x" to receive "d:\" change notifications from "this pc"). I can only conclude there is much more to pidls and ishellfolders than i have time and will to figure. I think i'll just run a background scan to monitor for changes myself.